# Spring Boot App works fine on IntelliJ but not in tomcat

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a Spring project (war format) in Tomcat. The project (https://github.com/iku747/DemoTec2) works fine in IntelliJ. However when i try to run war in Tomcat it only loads the first .jsp (login.jsp) and then if i try to do anything it said error404 resource not found. 
I dont know what's happening, can anyone help me?

Information:
The project uses Spring MVC + spring boot + spring security + maven
Tomcat version: 8.5.23
Any other information about versions etc can be found on the github.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any error in your catalena.out console

Comment: I dont see any error on my catalina.out (i'm looking for it in C/Program Files/ApacheSoftware Foundation/Tomcat 8.5/ logs

Comment: Loocking the "localhost_Acces_log" file i found that:
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2017:12:37:29 +0100] "GET /demoTec6/login HTTP/1.1" 200 4521
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2017:12:37:29 +0100] "GET /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1035
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2017:12:37:29 +0100] "GET /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1033
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2017:12:37:38 +0100] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 404 995

Why the app cant access those resources if in local it dont have any problem?

Comment: When you say that the app works fine in intellij you mean that you run it as a SpringBoot app or that you have a tomcat configuration inside your intellij ? Also did you follow the documentation for classic deployment ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

Comment: Yes, i mean that with the embedded tomcat works fine (launched from springboot funcionality with maven).
I think it may be a routing problem, because my project in local works with the route (*/login, for example) and when i generate it works with (PorjectName/login), it could be the cause?